# Horizontal checkbox layout with label underneath

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I just started coding a small page for myself after not doing any web design for a couple of years. As I now learned, laying out the page with tables is not state-of-the-art anymore (not sure if it ever really was).

Now I am trying to layout my page with CSS but couldn't find anything on:

1. How to align 7 checkboxes horizontally and put the corresponding label centered below the checkboxes?
2. How to align 2 selects horizontally and put the corresponding label centered above the selects?

The initial pure table-code was the following:

```css
.form fieldset {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid #c6c7cc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.form label {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 5px;
}
.form input,
.form select {
  display: table-cell;
}
.form .cssRow {
  display: table-row;
}
.form .submit {
  display: table-cell;
  caption-side: bottom;
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Name</td>
    <td align="left">
      <input name="name" type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Day(s) of week</td>
    <td align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="mo" checked>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="tu" checked>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="we" checked>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="th" checked>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="fr" checked>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="sa" checked>
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <input type="checkbox" name="day[]" value="su" checked>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">Mo</td>
          <td align="center">Tu</td>
          <td align="center">We</td>
          <td align="center">Th</td>
          <td align="center">Fr</td>
          <td align="center">Sa</td>
          <td align="center">Su</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="right">Validity</td>
    <td align="center">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Valid from</td>
          <td>Valid to</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>January</option>
              <option>February</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td>
            <select>
              <option>January</option>
              <option>February</option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Refresh">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

My CSS attempt so far looks like this:

<div class="form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Search</legend>
    <div class="cssRow">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30">
    </div>
    <div class="cssRow">
      <label for="day[]">Day(s) of week</label>
      <input name="day[]" type="text" value="ToDo" size="30" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="cssRow">
      <label>Validity</label>
      <input type="text" value="ToDo" size="30" disabled>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Suchen">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

To illustrate my problem, I created the following JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c9a7ezyk/

Any suggestions are welcome, although I prefer a simple solution, as I am just (re)learning HTML and CSS.

Comment: Looks perfect to me, what is wrong with the example you provided?

Comment: That the CSS version does not have any checkboxes/selects because I have no idea how to align/order them like I did with tables. I want to replace the table-design with the CSS-design and not complement it.

Comment: Oh, you want to stop using tables, I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer a slightly different approach to the other answer, where the `<input>` element is nested inside of a `<label>`, this implicitly associates the label with the input to give all kinds of nice bonuses.

It also makes for a simpler to follow markup, with less nested containers.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6q40r2qf/)**

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="label">Sunday</span>
</label>
```

And then

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
span.label {
    display: block;
}
```

Notice how clicking *the labels* check the associated checkbox properly. Selects behave exactly the same way. Because `<input>` and `<select>` are inlines by default, it means that they'll be affected by `text-align: center`.

Comment: A label element cannot contain block-level elements (a `div` inside a `label` is not valid). Why not just wrap them all in a `div` and use the `label` what it was intended for?

Comment: @VinceCgto Fixed, and I do think that it makes for a nicer to read markup this way. A `<label>` can most certainly be used this way, and it's also in the specs.

Comment: Hmmm yeah, definitely valid alright. But I don't see the benefits of this. Okay, you might have a little bit more space you can click on the check the checkbox, but that's negligible. I'd use a `div` to group them, but that's just semantic me talking ;)

Comment: @VinceCgto more clickable area is most definitely not negligible, especially on touch devices with tiny screens.

Answer (score 2):

Checkbox with label:

```
<div class="checkbox-label">
  <label for="checkbox">Sunday</label>
  <div class="checkbox-container">
    <input name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>

.checkbox-label {
  display: inline-block
}

.checkbox-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Notice that the checkbox is inline so you can put it in a container and use text-align: center

Also notice that I use display: inline-block on .checkbox-label so that they can be aligned horizontally (block elements, default for div, takes up a whole line and drops the following element beneath it)

I use the same principals for the selects
You can see the whole thing here:
http://codepen.io/Vall3y/pen/QwdWOe

Comment: Awesome, looks exactly like I want it to. I'll accept your answer as soon as I got the time to fully test it.

Comment: This is nice and all, but you should really associate a label with that input.

Comment: Swap that label class for a regular `label` element as @SecondRikudo states and your answer is by far the best.

Comment: I have modified my answer according to the comments. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: Also, you don't need that checkbox-container if you set the label to `display: block`.

Comment: @Vall3y It's still not OK because the label is not associated with the input. You can either do as I have in my answer, or use `for=` on the label with an `id=` on the input.

Answer (score 1):

## Semantic Purity

I am a bit of an HTML purist, so here is an HTML form without any extra markup:

- The legends are floated to the left and vertically centered using a line-height that matches the legends height
- The inputs are wrapped in a label with `display: inline-block` which is given a width to force the text below / above the input
- The `fieldset:before` properties allow us to vertically center the labels with `vertical-align: middle`

#### Full Example

The background colours are just to illustrate the layout.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  height: 70px;
}
fieldset:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  background: #F90;
  width: 0;
}
legend {
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 70px;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #F90;
  float: left;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.days label {
  background: #F90;
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.validity label {
  background: #F90;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset class="days">
    <legend>Day(s) of Week</legend>
    <label for="monday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="monday" />Mo
    </label>
    <label for="tuesday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="tuesday" />Tu
    </label>
    <label for="wednesday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="wednesday" />We
    </label>
    <label for="thursday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="thursday" />Th
    </label>
    <label for="friday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="friday" />Fr
    </label>
    <label for="saturday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="saturday" />Sa
    </label>
    <label for="sunday">
      <input type="checkbox" id="sunday" />Su
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="validity">
    <legend>Validity</legend>
    <label for="from">Valid From
      <select id="from">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    <label for="to">Valid to
      <select id="to">
        <option>Option</option>
      </select>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: It's pointless to use `for` and `id` if you're nesting the input in the label. It's implicitly associated.

Comment: @SecondRikudo - pointless, maybe. But if there are other form inputs not nested, they should have `for` and `id`. No harm in them all matching.

Answer (score -1):

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/c9a7ezyk/18/)

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<div>Name&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text"></input></div><br>

<div>Day(s) of week</div>

<div style="margin-left: 120px;margin-top: -25px;">

    <div><input type="checkbox" checked><br>Mo</input></div>

    <div style="
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: -37px;">
        <input type="checkbox" checked><br>Tu</input></div>

    <div style="
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: -37px;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked><br>We</input></div>

    <div style="
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-top: -37px;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked><br>Th</input></div>

    <div style="
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-top: -37px;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked><br>Fr</input></div>

    <div style="
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: -37px;">
    <input type="checkbox" checked><br>Sa</input></div>

    <div style="
    width: 10px;
    margin-left: 180px;
    margin-top: -37px;"><input type="checkbox" checked><br>Su</input>
    </div>

</div>
<br>

<div>Validity
    <select>
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
    </select>

    <select>
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
    </select>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inline styles are a bad practice. You shouldn't use them in this case.